# Iterative Matrix Factorization with Pytorch problem

Tags: python, pytorch

Imagine I have a user-item interaction matrix of 1194x412 for recommender systems.
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHdkM.png][1]][1]

Where 1 in the matrix corresponds to user-item interaction and zero to no interaction.
I have to apply iterative matrix factorization using Pytorch.
Below is the code for it.

```
class MF(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, n_users: int, n_items: int, n_factors: int):
        """
        n_users - int - number of users.
        n_items - int - number of items.
        n_factors - int - dimensionality of the latent space.
        """
        
        super(MF, self).__init__()
        
        self.embedding_user = nn.Embedding(n_users, n_factors) 
        self.embedding_item = nn.Embedding(n_items, n_factors)
        
        
    def forward(self, user: torch.Tensor, item: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        We allow for some flexibility giving lists of ids as inputs:
        if the training data is small we can deal with it in a single forward pass,
        otherwise we could fall back to mini-batches, limiting users and items we pass
        every time.
        
        user - torch.Tensor - user_ids.
        item - torch.Tensor - item_ids.
        
        returns - torch.Tensor - Reconstructed Interaction matrix of shape (n_users, n_items).
        """
        
        res = (self.embedding_user(user) * self.embedding_item(item)).sum(1)
                
        return res


def compute_loss(logits: torch.Tensor, labels: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    logits - torch.Tensor - output of model.
    labels - torch.Tensor - labels / interaction matrix model should learn to reconstruct.
    
    returns - torch.Tensor - BCELoss over all logits and labels.
    """
    loss = None
    
    # TODO: YOUR IMPLEMENTATION.
    
    logits_projected = torch.sigmoid(logits)
    loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(logits_projected,labels)
    
    
    return loss

def train(model: nn.Module, train_data_inter: np.ndarray, epochs: int, optimizer, loss_func) -> list:
    """
    model - nn.Module - torch module to train.
    train_data_inter - np.ndarray - interaction matrix of the training data.
    epochs - int - number of epochs to perform.
    optimizer - optim - optimizer for training.
    loss_func - loss function for training.
    
    returns - list - list of loss values over all epochs.
    """
    losses = []
    
    model.train()
    
    # TODO: YOUR IMPLEMENTAION.
    
    #rows, cols = train_data_inter
    #p = np.random.permutation(len(rows))
    #rows, cols = rows[p], cols[p]

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Set gradients to zero
        rows, cols = train_data_inter.nonzero()
        p = np.random.permutation(len(rows))
        rows, cols = rows[p], cols[p]

        for row, col in zip(*(rows, cols)):
        # Set gradients to zero
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Turn data into tensors
            rating = torch.FloatTensor([train_data_inter[row, col]])
            row = torch.LongTensor([row])
            col = torch.LongTensor([col])

            # Predict and calculate loss
            prediction = model(row, col)
            loss = loss_func(prediction, rating)
            
            losses.append(loss)

            # Backpropagate
            loss.backward()

            # Update the parameters
            optimizer.step()

    
            
    return losses

# Do not change the seed.
torch.manual_seed(1234)
rnd.seed(1234)
np.random.seed(1234)

model_128 = None
optimizer = None

# TODO: YOUR IMPLEMENATION.
# Initialize the model and optimizer as prescribed

model_128 = MF(train_data_inter.shape[0],train_data_inter.shape[1] ,n_factors=128)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_128.parameters(),lr=0.001)


loss_model_128 = train(model=model_128, 
                       train_data_inter=train_data_inter, 
                       epochs=10, 
                       optimizer=optimizer, 
                       loss_func=compute_loss)

assert len(loss_model_128) == 10, "Loss should have 1000 elements, one for each epoch."
```

Now the problem is the kernel is shutdown after a long time. It does not train. Could someone please check my functions if they are correct. I have looked at it but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Some libraries used

````
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

from tqdm import tqdm```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHdkM.png
````